# library(caret) returns namespace load failed and Object sigma not found

Tags: namespaces, r-caret

I have reviewed and did all the recommended actions here for caret package with no luck, I am still getting this error.

`> library(caret)
Error in get(n, ns) : object 'sigma' not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’`

I have reinstalled R and the package as well but still receiving the same error. This is my sessionInfo()

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 10586)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.1.0   lattice_0.20-33 stringi_1.0-1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.4      codetools_0.2-14 foreach_1.4.3    MASS_7.3-45     
 [5] grid_3.2.5       plyr_1.8.3       nlme_3.1-127     gtable_0.2.0    
 [9] magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.0     reshape2_1.4.1   minqa_1.2.4     
[13] nloptr_1.0.4     Matrix_1.2-4     splines_3.2.5    lme4_1.1-12     
[17] iterators_1.0.8  tools_3.2.5      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.3   
[21] parallel_3.2.5   colorspace_1.2-6 nnet_7.3-12`
```

Note: I posted this question after completely trying all the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, so that's how I tackled it:

I've downloaded oldest version of pbrktest package (it used by caret somehow) from CRAN, here's link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html

Then I've installed it, loaded it, and after that caret was available.

Hope it'll help you.